# Can pexpect be told to ignore a pattern or signal?

Tags: python, regex, pexpect

I'm trying to write a python script to access several Cisco network devices.  Sadly the devices are not set up the same, some have banners up that appear at weird places.  These banners might have the patterns that have some of the same stuff a prompt might have.

For example, once I log in I expect a prompt of `'hostname#'`, so I basically use a `pexpect('#')`  I might have to handle certain other prompts such as `'hostname>'` as well so `pexpect('>')` works.  I'll really have a list of possible prompts, plus a timeout and act accordingly.

This is fine unless a banner shows up in the middle somewhere.  For example, after logging in a banner might show up that says  `## Welcome ##` and be there right before the prompt.  I believe if I could tell pexpect to ignore the regular expression `#.*\r` I'd be fine, but I'm not sure this is possible.  Is it possible to have pexpect ignore a string, or is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution I used to use back in the [BBS days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulletin_board_system) was to look for a prompt, and then immediately after I got one, look for a line break or a space with a timeout of a second or two. If the second wait timed out, that meant I was *really* waiting at a prompt.  Since `pexpect` uses regular expressions, you can actually check to see if you receive *any* character within a second after a prompt.

```
def wait_for_prompt(session, prompt, timeout=1):
    gotprompt = 0
    while not gotprompt:
        session.expect(prompt, timeout=None)
        gotprompt = session.expect([".", pexpect.TIMEOUT], timeout=timeout)

child = pexpect.spawn("ssh ...")
wait_for_prompt(child, "[#>] ?")
```

I've never actually used this library before so this may need some tweaking, but it's an approach I used successfully in the '80s. :-)

Comment: I ended up using this approach and it is the best approach IMO.

Answer (score 2):

The Python pexpect module waits for *matching* input. You can't actually ignore input, except by creating regular expressions that will not match ambiguous or undesirable input. Instead of creating one really complex regex, though, pexpect can also handle [lists of regular expressions](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect#Lists_if_patterns). You then anchor those regular expressions to reduce ambiguity.

For example, you can easily differentiate between a command prompt and a banner by anchoring the match to the start or end of the line, and making the match as exact as possible:

```
users = ['fred', 'ginger']
user_prompt = '^(?:%s)@.*?\$ $' % '|'.join(users)
child.expect (['hostname# $', 'hostname> $', user_prompt])
```

They key is to understand what input you want to match, build an unambiguous regular expression with anchors, and then update your expressions whenever you find a mismatch--which hopefully won't be too often because you didn't create overly-greedy patterns in the first place.

Comment: This kind of pattern matching will not work as pexpect cannot handle the '$' as you would expect (no pun intended).  The same is true for '^'.  See http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect

Comment: @WildBill You're right. The expression was meant to be illustrative of the concept of anchoring, but wasn't heavily tested. If you have a working example of an anchored expression with pexpect, I'll be glad to update my answer. Otherwise, I think the answer remains conceptually valid, even if future visitors need to [rework the EOL anchors](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect#Find_the_end_of_line_--_CR.2FLF_conventions) slightly.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to handle anchored expressions (at least not when expecting the prompt).  You can look for new lines '\n', but a new line does not exist when a prompt is given.  It's the classic halting problem:  "How do I know this is THE last line/character?"  I'm unsure if this issue only exists in pexpect or all expect utilizations...

Answer (score 0):

Once expect has found a match it sets the 'before', 'after', and 'match' attributes on the process instance. You could use these to write some logic.

Alternatively you could just craft a better regex that only matches the prompt that you want. Even r'>$|#$' would probably do what you want since it is only going to match those characters at the end of a line.

Comment: r'>$|#$' won't provide anything better as it is possible there could be a line in a banner that ends with # or >