# pexpect to ignore certain lines in command-line runtime

Tags: python, pexpect

So I have a script that automatically reboots a device:

> In run time:
>
> MASTER> reboot
>
> MASTER>
>
> Are you sure you want to reboot (YES|NO):
>
> !!!!!!!!!!
>
> MASTER>

My code:

```
child.expect('MASTER>')
child.sendline('reboot')


child.expect('MASTER>')
child.expect('Are you sure you want to reboot (YES|NO)')
child.sendline('YES')
```

Problem:

How to I skip the junk characters "!!!!!!!" that come in between and go to "MASTER>" again?

Right now my code stops functioning after 'YES'

EDIT:

I actually found that the code spawns a new process for the reboot to happen.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly causes the junk characters to appear? Could you try testing the results of the YES NO question until it matches'YES'?

Comment: The junk characters appear to show the user that a reboot is happening..

Comment: I think I found my answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853412/can-pexpect-be-told-to-ignore-a-pattern-or-signal


Thanks